# How do you make a menu scroll with the page, but leave the logo

Tags: css, logging, scroll, move

I wasnt to make something like [this](http://totalfratmove.com) site where I can scroll up and down and my menu goes with me, but the logo remains at the top. How did they do this? I tried some CSS, but was not able to get the logo to stay in his place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's called a persistent header, it's too long to explain on here so you can use this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

Comment: a name and a link to a tutorial is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, be sure to give the person credit by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 0):

You can start with position:fixed and defining either top and left properties or bottom and left properties.

This web can help you too : [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)